# Suddenly no internet connection on WD MyBook Live

Tags: linux, networking, unix, internet, nas

I have a WD MyBook Live NAS drive on a remote connection that has suddenly and inexplicably lost it's ability to access the Internet.  It still has local network connectivity.  I have RDP access to a workstation on the same network, so I can access the HTTP control panel and SSH in via the local network (the OS is *-nix based, BSD I think).

It's not a DNS problem:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

This just exhausts and times out.

Other troubleshooting steps taken:

- All of the IP and routing information appears to be correct and has not been changed
- There is no IP conflict on the network
- The NAS device does not have `iptables`
- `/etc/hosts.deny` is empty
- I have rebooted the NAS and the router
- No configurations are applied on the router that should cause this

I'll have someone onsite tomorrow physically power cycle the unit and try another Ethernet cable, but beyond that, I'm at a loss.  What else could it be?

**EDIT**

Good grief.  The gateway IP in the NAS's TCP/IP configuration was wrong.  I don't even know how this happened, it appears the router has an usual operation that uses two different IP addresses as it's gateway and one of them just ... stopped working?  I don't even know.

**EDIT 2**

The cause of the problem was ultimately [buggy firmware on the modem/router/gateway device](https://superuser.com/questions/1679915/cant-configure-hitron-coda-cable-modem-router-with-192-168-100-x-lan-subnet/1690890#1690890).

Comment: Read [this](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/wd-my-book-live-two-hacks) and check if you are affected by the exploits, or potentially a new exploit that killed something else.

Comment: @dirkt: interesting, thanks for the link.  I've disabled remote http access on the device (not needed), however, port forwarding on the router was not enabled for that.  There also does not appear to be any data loss.

Comment: The cause of the problem was ultimately [buggy firmware on the modem/router/gateway device](https://superuser.com/questions/1679915/cant-configure-hitron-coda-cable-modem-router-with-192-168-100-x-lan-subnet/1690890#1690890).

Comment: You can also answer your own question (and accept the answer); it may help somebody else with the same problems. Comments are not guaranteed to stick around.