# Can't configure Hitron CODA cable modem/router with 192.168.100.x LAN subnet

Tags: networking, subnet

I had to factory reset this cable modem/router due to some unexplained connectivity issues.  For some reason, I cannot provide it a LAN IP on `192.168.100.x`.  It just fails with this weird engrish error:

> [ERROR]
>
> The IP address are reserved, please check.

Before factory reset, it was configured with `192.168.100.254` as the gateway IP, which is what a bunch of static clients expect to see.  I tried disconnecting all clients except for the one connecting to configure, and it gives the same error.

This is on a Shaw cable Internet connection in Canada.  Their support has been useless.  There is nowhere to check or update the firmware, I suspect the device is nerfed.

Edit: called Shaw again. Remote firmware update likely torched it and is preventing the use of this configuration.

Comment: What exactly is the LAN IP you're trying to give it when you get the error - or is it with any, also with IPs in other subnets like 192.168.1.0/24? Please don't answer in a comment, update the question instead.

Comment: @Peregrino69: `192.168.100.254`

Comment: Sort of makes sense as that IP is indeed reserved. If you ping that address from a connected computer which has IP in 192.168.100.0/24 network, what's the result?

Comment: It is not reserved by standard nor by convention. It sounds like something specific to this router model – could be deliberate (for unknown reasons), could be a bug (e.g. if they tried to "reserve" 255 but mistyped it as 254).

Comment: @user1686: as it turns out, this is correct.  Shaw finally confirmed that it is a reserved space specifically for this model (or possibly series of models).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shaw confirmed:

- The subnet is reserved for this model (and possibly others) for administration purposes
- A firmware update removed the ability to enter this subnet, but it was retained because it was initially configured in the previous version of the firmware (which also explains the connectivity issues, because it was causing all sorts of IP conflicts)
- The subnet was (possibly mistakenly) **not** reserved in previous versions of the firmware